# Running HAProxy with Lua Scripts

Tags: makefile, lua, ld, haproxy

I am trying to build HAProxy-1.9 with `USE_LUA=1` flag to enable lua support. This the `make` command I am using:

```
sudo make TARGET=linux USE_DL=1 USE_CRYPT_H=1 USE_LUA=1 LUA_LIB=/usr/bin/lua5.3 LUA_INC=/usr/include/lua5.3/ LUA_LIB_NAME=lua53
```

When I execute the make command I receive the following error:

```
  LD      haproxy
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -llua53
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 make: *** [Makefile:976: haproxy] Error 1
```

From what I have gathered it seems that a one of the library file (guessing a socket file) is either missing or, I have provided a wrong directory. I am using `OpenSuse Tumbleweed`.

**EDIT 1**

I was able to make `haproxy` from source by changing `TARGET=linux` to `TARGET=generic`. After the make file stopped, no errors were reported on stdout. However, `haproxy.service` was not installed.

I previously had haproxy installed using `zypper`. The only reason I removed it was to reinstall it with `USE_LUA=1` flag because I was not sure whether it was possible to edit haproxy post compilation to change a compile time configuration.

After reinstalling, it is working. However, I believe there is an error with `lua-load`. When I try `lua-load /usr/share/haproxy/auth-request.lua` I get the following error from running `journalctl -xe: error in lua file '/tmp/auth-request.lua': cannot open /tmp/auth-request.lua: Permission denied`
. The permission set on the file was `haproxy:haproxy` as in the `haproxy.cfg` file. I have tried also tried modifying `user root group root` in `haproxy.cfg` and `chown /tmp/auth-request.lua root:root`. The error is still there.

I may have deviated somewhat from the original question. I would appreciate it is still possible to solve this problem. If more information or context is required, it can be provided.

**EDIT 2**

Most recently I tried adding read and execute permissions for all users on `/tmp/auth-request.lua`. `ls -l` output:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3957 Feb 25 02:24 /tmp/auth-request.lua
```

Comment: Probably, you must install `lua` prior to installing `haproxy`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I have installed; `lua -v
Lua 5.3.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2017 Lua.org, PUC-Rio`

Comment: Try `LUA_LIB_NAME=lua5.3`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I have made an edit on the post. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Okay after some painstaking hours, I was able to fix the permission issue as per **EDIT 2** in the post. I moved my Lua script to the haproxy config directory and that seemed to have worked. Although, I am not too sure whether `/etc/haproxy` is a good location to keep Lua scripts but, for now it has worked.